# Elasticseach - document that match more terms has lower score than one that match fewer

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a query that is supposed to return profiles with similar interests. The problem is that document with **more** matching terms is scored lower.

In `bool` query, I have `should` with `interests = ['games', 'music', 'sport']`

Document with `interests = ['games']` gets score 0.14981213

Document with `interests = ['games', 'music']` gets score 0.11516824.

Why? Im using AWS elasticsearch, v. 2.3.2.

The query looks like:

```
{
    "explain": true,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "id": 3918
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "interests": [
                            "games",
                            "music",
                            "sport"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}
```

Then, results I'm getting:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_explanation": {
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "description": "# clause",
                                    "details": [],
                                    "value": 0.0
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "-id:`\b\u0000\u0000\u001eN #*:*, product of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "description": "boost",
                                            "details": [],
                                            "value": 1.0
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "description": "queryNorm",
                                            "details": [],
                                            "value": 0.4494364
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "value": 0.4494364
                                }
                            ],
                            "value": 0.0
                        },
                        {
                            "description": "product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "description": "sum of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "description": "weight(interests:games in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                                    "details": [
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=3)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "queryNorm",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.4494364
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 0.4494364
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "fieldWeight in 1, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                                                    "details": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                                            "details": [],
                                                                            "value": 1.0
                                                                        }
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=3)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=1)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 1.0
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "value": 0.4494364
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "value": 0.4494364
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "value": 0.4494364
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "coord(1/3)",
                                    "details": [],
                                    "value": 0.33333334
                                }
                            ],
                            "value": 0.14981213
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": 0.14981213
                },
                "_id": "3917",
                "_index": "test_44024988_profiles",
                "_node": "urWXg5KhREyffYielaa6Rw",
                "_score": 0.14981213,
                "_shard": 2,
                "_source": {
                    "full_name": "Bob Doe",
                    "id": 3916,
                    "interests": [
                        "games"
                    ],
                    "user_id": 3917
                },
                "_type": "profile_document"
            },
            {
                "_explanation": {
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "description": "# clause",
                                    "details": [],
                                    "value": 0.0
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "-id:`\b\u0000\u0000\u001eN #*:*, product of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "description": "boost",
                                            "details": [],
                                            "value": 1.0
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "description": "queryNorm",
                                            "details": [],
                                            "value": 0.9173473
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "value": 0.9173473
                                }
                            ],
                            "value": 0.0
                        },
                        {
                            "description": "product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "description": "sum of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "description": "weight(interests:games in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                                    "details": [
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.30685282
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "queryNorm",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.9173473
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 0.2814906
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                                                    "details": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                                            "details": [],
                                                                            "value": 1.0
                                                                        }
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.30685282
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 0.30685282
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "value": 0.08637618
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "value": 0.08637618
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "description": "weight(interests:music in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "description": "score(doc=0,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                                    "details": [
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.30685282
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "queryNorm",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.9173473
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 0.2814906
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                                                    "details": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                                            "details": [],
                                                                            "value": 1.0
                                                                        }
                                                                    ],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 0.30685282
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)",
                                                                    "details": [],
                                                                    "value": 1.0
                                                                }
                                                            ],
                                                            "value": 0.30685282
                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    "value": 0.08637618
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "value": 0.08637618
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "value": 0.17275237
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "coord(2/3)",
                                    "details": [],
                                    "value": 0.6666667
                                }
                            ],
                            "value": 0.11516824
                        }
                    ],
                    "value": 0.11516824
                },
                "_id": "3918",
                "_index": "test_44024988_profiles",
                "_node": "urWXg5KhREyffYielaa6Rw",
                "_score": 0.11516824,
                "_shard": 4,
                "_source": {
                    "full_name": "Alex Test",
                    "id": 3917,
                    "interests": [
                        "games",
                        "music"
                    ],
                    "user_id": 3918
                },
                "_type": "profile_document"
            },
            ... # not interesting doc
        ],
        "max_score": 0.14981213,
        "total": 3
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 3
}
```

---

My input data:

```
[{
    "full_name": "Bob Doe",
    "id": 3916,
    "interests": [
        "games"
    ],
    "user_id": 3917
}, {
    "full_name": "Alex Test",
    "id": 3917,
    "interests": [
        "games",
        "music"
    ],
    "user_id": 3918
}, {
    "full_name": "Joe Test",
    "id": 3918,
    "user_id": 3919
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the scoring formula in the Elasticsearch.

```
score(q,d)  =  
            queryNorm(q)  
          · coord(q,d)    
          · ∑ (           
                tf(t in d)   
              · idf(t)²      
              · t.getBoost() 
              · norm(t,d)    
            ) (t in q)
```

The reference is the [practical scoring formula](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html), and you could get some descriptions here, if you do not know them. But the explanataion of your case will be pretty simple, it's just the formula the doing the stuff, and the combination of all these factors (**tf**, **idf**, **queryNorm**, etc.). Also, this could happen, if your index is dummy and just contain a couple of docs, than these values a pretty strange.

I could go deeply in the explanation, but mostly it's a scoring formula. If you want to fix it, that's another question, you could do that by doing different query

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. I understand the formula, but now there's a question - is the formula wrong or my expectations? I think that `filter` should not affect the score and `should` as a query should work strightforward.

Comment: yes, you're correct, filter doesn't affect the scoring and that's exactly what happens in your case, you just get scores from terms query. the thing is, that we could calculate the tf idf by hand, to see, if formula is doing exactly  the same, and trust me it will. tf idf is tricky, since it's taking into account rarity of the term

Comment: Im not telling that score is different than one given by the formula. Lets agree that it works correct considering the formula, but Im just wondering if it works correct considering common user expectations. But maybe thats only me.

Other thing is that it seem to be not stable. More context around this issue is that this is what I'm getting on CI server in unit tests, on my local machine score is "correct" (following my expectations). Even running with the same elasticsearch, just different index names.

Comment: could you provide your full sample data than?

Comment: I've added to the bottom of original question.